# Focus issue in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, focus, textfield

I have a default text in a tlftextfield that is to be deleted when first(!) clicking on it to enter some own text. However the textfield loses its focus when I attach a function to the FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN. This is what I have at the moment:

```
function clearField(event:FocusEvent) {
    if (event.currentTarget.text == defaultText[event.currentTarget.name]) {
        event.currentTarget.text="";
        event.currentTarget.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
    }
}
```

The handler is attached as follows:

```
rmDiagnose.txtDiagnose.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearField);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `setFocus()` method of the interaction manager (`ISelectionManager`). Note that the [documentation says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/edit/ISelectionManager.html#setFocus%28%29) this method is for setting focus on the container **that contains the selected text**.

This method specifically acts on text that you have selected w/the mouse. And in your scenario, there is no selected text.

So instead, just use the [usual means to focus an object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus). In your case:

```
stage.focus = InteractiveObject(event.currentTarget);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sunil. However, this does not work either: "Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:InteractiveObject." When I convert it to an interactive Object, it runs (no error when compiling) but does not work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Opps, my bad! You definitely need to cast `event.currentTarget` to an `InteractiveObject`. To help understand why it doesn't work after that, can you confirm what `event.currentTarget` is? And/or show how you attach the event listener? Lastly, if you have a reference to the text field, you can try to focus that instead: `stage.focus = myTextField`.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, for your continued support, it is very much appreciated. I have changed the code like you suggested but still no success. You can view the swf online at http://www.rexmedicus.com/assets/diagnosendose.swf and wait until a brown notebook appears reading "Differentialdiagnosen?" and "Untersuchungen?". These are the textfields in question. When you click on them, the text disappears but the focus is not correct so that you have to click again in order to write sth. Weird.